# In Terminal, how can you determine which shell is actually running?

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, unix

Using Terminal on OS X 10.11.4, initializing Terminal opens a new window running `bash` (by default). As I understand it, inputting `echo $SHELL` should output the shell that said command is submitted to. So, why do I get this output after switching from `bash` to `tcsh`?

```
[<dir>] <username>$ tsch
[<dir>] <username>% echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Try `echo $0`  $SHELL is set in your .profile as an environment variable.

Comment: @Allan - `echo $0` just gives me a blank line - there are non POSIX shells

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under `csh` family shells, you'll got your running shell with this command:

```
% echo $shell
```

If `csh` was run, directly or undirectly, from a Bourne family shell that had its SHELL variable exported, the latter being the common case, the SHELL variable would stay untouched so `echo $SHELL` will still show the its previous value which would be confusing.

This is what is happening to you, one of the parent processes of your `tcsh` session was `bash`. If `bash` is started with the `SHELL` variable unset, it sets it to the path to `bash`, despite what its documentation states. Note that launching a new Bourne shell family wouldn't have changed either the SHELL variable if set. SHELL is definitely not the way to identify what shell you are running, just to known which shell is your default shell when in a POSIX environment.

A portable way to know what shell is currently running would be:

```
ps -o comm= -p $$
```

However, the latter command assumes `$$` is set to the current process PID, which unfortunately some exotic shells like `fish` break. An even more portable way that workarounds this issue is:

```
env sh -c 'basename $(ps -o comm= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $$))'
```

Comment: Right: but as per my question, why is this outputting `/bin/bash` if I (supposedly) have switched from the default `bash` to `tcsh`?

Comment: Answer updated. `tcsh` doesn't touch the `SHELL` variable so if it has a value when `tcsh` is started, it stays that way.

Comment: Portable answer posted, `ps -o comm= -p $$` should work whatever the shell provided that shell correctly set `$$`, which `tcsh` should do.

Comment: That portable answer fails in fish so I think is a POSIX only answer as well

Comment: @Mark no, it is not POSIX only given the fact it works with `csh`, `tcsh` and the likes which are notoriously non POSIX. Answer updated anyway with a command that should work with much more shells, including `fish`.

Comment: It does work with fish and it gives the full path to the shell's execrable not just the shell name

Comment: @Mark Answer updated to workaround it.

Comment: @jlliagre I really appreciate the thorough response you put together here. I don't like the idea of changing after already accepting an answer, but in this case, your answer is the best one.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the shell you are running in.

If it is a POSIX confirming shell e.g. bash, ash,ash, sh, and some others e.g.  csh, tcsh then `echo $0` will return the shell's name

e.g.

```
~ $ bash
bash-3.2$ echo $0
bash
```

or

```
~ $ ksh
$ echo $0
ksh
```

However not all shells are POSIX e.g. I used to use ipython shell profile and now fish

Comment: Ah, yes: I entered `echo $0` and got the expected output: `tcsh`. I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer as it solves the specific example that I gave. That being said, do you know if `tcsh` (or any shell for that matter) is running in some sort of "emulated" state when I use `tcsh` to switch from the default `bash` rather than changing the default shell in the Terminal preferences to `tcsh` (or some other installed shell)?

Comment: @WatermarkBranding running tcsh from the command line is the same as running as the default shell (except for being called as a login shell by Terminal)

Comment: I really do appreciate your prompt response (and one which helped solve the example that I gave). That said, in all fairness, jllagre' response more thoroughly answers the question. I'm going to upvote your answer anyhow. Best.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to check which TTY your terminal is attached to and check which shell is running on that tty. Then you could look at the PID (Process ID) and PPID (Parent Process ID) in case your shell has spawned another shell as a child process:

```
MacBook:~$ w
15:16  up 8 days, 16:11, 2 users, load averages: 1.26 1.22 1.24
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
myuser   console  -                19Apr16 8days -
myuser   s000     -                15:15       - w
MacBook:~$ ps -ef | grep s000
UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0 23865   293   0  3:15PM ttys000    0:00.14 login -pf myuser /bin/bash
  501 23866 23865   0  3:15PM ttys000    0:00.05 -bash
    0 23992 23866   0  3:16PM ttys000    0:00.01 ps -ef
  501 23993 23866   0  3:16PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep s000
MacBook:~$
```

In the example above, using the `w` command, I've found out that the user `myuser` is logged in to the `console` (ignore this one) and also to `s000`.

I then ran `ps -ef` and just looking at the PID and PPID columns, I can see that `login` (PID 23865) has executed `bash` (PID 23866, PPID 23865), which then ran two processes: `ps -ef` (PID 23992, PPID 23866) and `grep s000` (PID 23993 PPID 23866).

If, for some reason, I executed `tcsh` from `bash`, running the above commands would still allow me to see which shell is my current command executed by.

Answer (score 1):

When you start a terminal session in OS X the `login` utility is called.

From the man page:

```
The login utility enters information into the environment (see environ(7)) specifying the user's home directory (HOME), command inter-
preter (SHELL), search path (PATH), terminal type (TERM) and user name (both LOGNAME and USER).

Some shells may provide a builtin login command which is similar or identical to this utility.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page.
```

Note the options used when the utility is called then read the man page:

```
ps -ef | grep -w [l]ogin
```

Some of this information was gleaned from your record in opendirectory.

```
dscl . -read /Users/your_user_name RecordName UserShell NFSHomeDirectory
```